# Set UIAlert to appear after x amount of IBAction presses

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

Is there a simple way of setting a piece of code to check for a certain amount of presses before using a UIAlertView,

For example,

If the IBAction has been pressed 30 times, then we would like to show a UIAlertView, I can do the Alert, it's just the figuring how to count 30 presses?

Thanks to you both, I have gotten a little further, here is the code, I am using count as the int here;

It works, but the aim is that if the user has purchased the upgrade then the count is ignored... At the moment, even if the user upgrades, they still get that UIAlert on every 30 presses

```
- (IBAction)setRandomText {

    selectedRecNumber = (arc4random() % kMaxRecords);
    NSString *text = [allText objectAtIndex:selectedRecNumber];
   [randomText setText:text];
    count++;

    if (![MKStoreManager featureBPurchased] ) {

        if(count == 30)
        {
            count = 0;

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Limit" message:@"Reached the Limit!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"OK",nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];


    }else{

    }
}

}
```

--- EDIT fixed using this method;

```
   if (kMaxRecords == 35) {

            if(count == 30)
            {
                count = 0;

}else{

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily count that by yourself.
Just create an `int` variable and then increment it each time user presses the button.
Also check if the number is bigger or equal to 30 and if it is, then reset it and show the UIAlertView.

This is some pseudo code.

```
@interface YourClass : ParentClass {
   int numberOfPresses = 0;
}
@end

@implementation YourClass
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
   numberOfPresses += 1;
   if (numberOfPresses >= 30) {
      numberOfPresses = 0;
      UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Your Alert" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
      [alert show];
   }
}
@end
```

Comment: What does method `featureBPurchased` exactly do? This code looks correct.

Comment: featureBPurchased enables all colors in the array, instead of just 30 colors (hence the prompt at 30 presses) but for some reason even when purchased that prompt still appears after 30 presses

Comment: Then the problem must be in that method. Try setting some breakpoints and see if the method returns YES or NO, when it should or shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to have a static variable in the method to count the presses:

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    static NSUInteger presses = 0;

    presses++;

    if(presses == 30)
    {
        presses = 0;

        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil] show];
    }
}
```